# Why am not able to render this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, ckeditor5

I am building a React Typescript app, and using CKEditor, a method gives me this object :

[image]

And when i try to render it, it gives me this error :

[image]

Can someone explain to me what am i doing wrong ?

Here's the code :

```
export default class Toolbar extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  public toolbar: ToolbarView | undefined

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.toolbar = new ToolbarView()
    this.toolbar.render()
    console.log(this.toolbar.element) // the result is the first screenshot
  }

  public render() {
    return this.toolbar ? this.toolbar.element : null
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to include a DOM element directly into your `render` method - that won't work. Have you read the [docs page on integrating with other libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)?

Comment: @JoeClay I have read some, but this doesn't seem helpful: I'd like to know how i can turn my object into a comprehensible object for react so it can render it, or use a React method to achieve that. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i was able to achieve this using `ReactRef`:

```
  public toolbarRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = React.createRef()

  public componentDidMount() {
    // this.editor initialisation

    this.toolbar = new ToolbarView()
    // adding stuff to the toolbar
    this.toolbar.render()

    const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.toolbarRef.current as HTMLDivElement)
    if (el instanceof Element) {
      el.appendChild(this.toolbar.element)
    }
  }

  public render() {
    return (
        <div ref={this.toolbarRef} />
    )
  }
```